# how can I get the latest entries from a transactional table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sequel

This is a bit "out of the box" from usual AREL or Sequel gem based models, so I'm looking for some expert guidance.

I have a legacy (transactional) table outside of my app that gets updated every time something is deployed. `Deployments` looks something like this:

```
    DEPLOY_ID | APP_DEPLOY_NAME | DEPLOY_TYPE | DOMAIN | DEPLOY_ENV | ...
    1         | adn             | dta         | ruby   | dev1       | ...
    2         | adn             | dta         | ruby   | dev1       | ...      
  * 3         | adn             | dta         | ruby   | dev1       | ...
  * 4         | adn             | dta         | ruby   | dev2       | ...
  * 5         | adnb            | dta         | ruby   | dev1       | ...
```

The marked lines above represent the highest `DEPLOY_ID` per unique `APP_DEPLOY_NAME + DEPLOY_TYPE + DOMAIN + DEPLOY_ENV` entry.  Conceptually, these are the *latest* deployments for a composite key defined by those four values.

In SQL I can create this view with a self-join easily:

```
select deployments.* from
  -- deploy_max
  (select max(DEPLOY_ID) as DEPLOY_ID from DEPLOYMENTS
  group by APP_DEPLOY_NAME, DEPLOY_TYPE, DOMAIN, DEPLOY_ENV) deploy_max 
join DEPLOYMENTS as deployments on 
  deploy_max.DEPLOY_ID = deployments.DEPLOY_ID
order by deployments.APP_DEPLOY_NAME asc, 
         deployments.DEPLOY_TYPE asc, 
         deployments.DOMAIN asc
```

(there's likely a better way of writing that, but it shows what I'm trying to do)

However, this loses the benefits of query chaining... i.e. I can't seem to get something like:  `latest.filter(:APP_DEPLOY_NAME.like('%adn%'))`.

Other wrinkles:

- I don't own the db, so I can't add a view.
- If I create my own table, I need to worry about data refresh (the transactional table is live and gets updated continuously).

Any ideas?

Comment: So, ignoring the title of your question, your actual question is how to create a Sequel dataset that creates this joined view?

Comment: Sure, that would work, do you have a solution?  (I didn't want to limit the responses to Sequel vs. AREL since I've been working with both and would welcome approaches in either -- also, the way I'm doing this in SQL may be the 'hard way' and maybe there is a different way to rethink the whole problem that is easier -- that's why I made the title as general as possible.)

Comment: I should add that it isn't as simple as `DB[sql_statement]`, because while that is a trivial way to get a dataset, the dataset does not (apparently?) apply query chaining rules.  Maybe there is a more advanced way of writing your own extensions to the ORM that handles this, but I had trouble finding examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward translation of your SQL query to Sequel code:

```
DB[:deployments].
  select{max(deploy_id).as(deploy_id)}.
  group(:app_deploy_name, :deploy_type, :domain, :deploy_env).
  from_self(:alias=>:deploy_max).
  join(:deployments, :deploy_id=>:deploy_id).
  select_all(:deployments).
  order(:deployments__app_deploy_name, :deployments__deploy_type, :deployments__domain)
```